# Why is hook not reusable?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I created a custom hook as follows:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export const useMyHook = () => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  function toggle() {
    setIsVisible(!isVisible);
  }

  return { isVisible, toggle,}
};
```

I am only able to use it once (see comment below). When I call the hook again with different const, I get the error:

> Property 'isVisible2' does not exist on type '{ isVisible: boolean; toggle: () => void; }'.  TS2339

```
import React from 'react';
import useModal from './useMyHook';

export const App = () => {

  const {isVisible, toggle} = useMyHook();    // Example of using once
  const {isVisible2, toggle2} = useMyHook();  // am not able to use it here
  const {isVisible3, toggle3} = useMyHook();  // am not able to use it here

  return (<div> Hello world! </div>);
};
```

I am incorrectly assuming that creating a new **const** var allows the reuse of the hook. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, you're returning an object with two properties: `isVisible` and `toggle`.

Either destructure into differently-named variables (verbose; not great):

```
const {isVisible: isVisible2, toggle: toggle2} = useMyHook();
```

Or return an array from the hook instead:

```
return [isVisible, toggle];
```

and

```
const [isVisible2, toggle2] = useMyHook();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in your custom hook, you return an object with 2 properties: isVisible and toggle.
But you destructured it into isVisible2 and toggle2. You can see, there are no isVisible2 and toggle2 in your return.
So, if you want to use this hook again try to assign it to a new variable name like this:

```
const {isVisible: isVisible2, toggle: toggle2} = useMyHook();
```